# Blend for Visual Studio 2015 "New Sample Data Failed"

Tags: visual-studio, blend

I am starting to use Blend 2015. Never used and never developed apps for Windows, so I started following an online course (Developer's Guide to Windows 10 App Development). All well until the instructions were to add a new "Sample Data" to the "basic app". I get a pop-up saying "New Sample Data failed". I have already tried re-installing Visual Studio 2015, but after a whole day of uninstalling, repairing, re-installing, I still get the pop-up. Goggled for it. Nothing. Anyone got an idea what may be wrong?
Thanks

Comment: Re-uninstalled the whole VisualStudio 2015 package and annexed packages. Re-installed from ISO. Rebooted a couple of times (just in case :)!)... Same problem. Now, I have a Samsung laptop i5 2.3 GHz with 6GB of RAM. It takes several minutes to open a solution ... Either I have done something wrong, or this great idea of all integrated, universal app, blend, all-in-one do-it-all super-tool is really not a viable solution ... Hopefully I have done something wrong .. but what??